# Python passing values to another function calculator program

Tags: python, global-variables

```
#This part of the code will only get numbers from user
while True:
#Using while True will allow me to loop and renter if user input is wrong. While True will go above Try Catch
    try:
# Using try: and except: will allow to end the program without crash however then need to be indented
# Try goes before the def name
        def getNumbers():

            num1=int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
            num2=int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))


        getNumbers()
        break# the while will stop when both values are numbers
    except:
        print("Incorrect input detected, try again")

#This part of the code will add the 2 numbers
def addNums():
    What do I put here so that  I can use num1+num2
    addNums()

def subNums():
    What do I put here so that  I can use num1-num2
    addNums()
```

I wrote a Calculator program but over there I declared those num1 and num2 as global variables in side getNumbers def. Someone mentioned that is not a good/ideal way which is why I wanted to try this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: what code do i put inside addNums() and subNums() method in order to use num1 num2?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to use global variables inside of a function, use the `global` keyword:

```
x = 1
y = 2
def add() :
    global x, y
    return x + y
```

**EDIT**

Actually, your "question" is really unclear. You say you are not willing to use global-variables in your code, but you wrote:

```
def addNums():
    What do I put here so that  I can use num1+num2
    addNums()
```

The problem is that `num1` and `num2` *don't exist* at this place. If you want to use them, then they *are* global variables.

As far as I understand, what you want is just a function:

```
def addNums(x, y):
    return x+y

addNums(num1, num2)
```

Comment: I do not wish to add/use global variable. I mentioned that I already have a solution using global, besides I am taking user input not hard coded value of x,y. Thanks

Comment: @SheikhRahman I don't think it's too difficult to replace `x = 1` by `x = int(input())`. Besides, if you don't want to use global variables, don't tag global-variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your doubt, it's not clear in your post.
Why can't you do in this way (just for e.g, you can make it better):--

> Blockquote

```
def subNums(a, b):
    return (a - b)

def addNums(a, b):
    return (a + b)

def getNumbers():
    while True:
        try:
            num1 = int(input("Enter 1st number: "))
            num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd number: "))        
            return (num1, num2)
        except:
            print("Incorrect input detected, try again")

a, b = getNumbers()
print ("sum of %d and %d : %d" % (a, b, addNums(a, b)))
print ("difference of %d and %d : %d" % (a, b, subNums(a, b)))
```

Hope this will help.